# How to use T-SQL Update to change case sensitive results

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

These are the results I got for the the table Account Ex

[image]

I need to use T-SQL to change some of the results that have 'new' or 'NEW' to just 'New'

I attempted this code below is this correct

```sql
UPDATE Account Ex
Set[1f9ae786-9aae-4478-8254-3b683804ccfa] = 'New'
WHERE [1f9ae786-9aae-4478-8254-3b683804ccfa] COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS = 'NEW' AND 'new'
```

Comment: `AND 'new'` what? That's only half a boolean expression.

Comment: Side Note; A GUID is an odd choice for a column's name.

Comment: You could try this: `UPDATE AccountEx SET [1f9ae786-9aae-4478-8254-3b683804ccfa] = 'New'
WHERE LOWER([1f9ae786-9aae-4478-8254-3b683804ccfa]) = 'new'`. It's a bit blunt and does not perform very well, but I assume you want to either run this only once in a while, or make sure that only correct values will be entered by client applications, or make some redesigns to your data model to avoid such kinds of issues in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server's default collation is case insensitive, so this might do what you want:

```
UPDATE AccountEx
     Set [1f9ae786-9aae-4478-8254-3b683804ccfa] = 'New'
     WHERE [1f9ae786-9aae-4478-8254-3b683804ccfa] = 'new';
```

Alternatively, this should work regardless of collation:

```
UPDATE AccountEx
     Set [1f9ae786-9aae-4478-8254-3b683804ccfa] = 'New'
     WHERE lower([1f9ae786-9aae-4478-8254-3b683804ccfa]) = 'new';
```

The only downside is that this updates all rows that have "new" in any case.  If the table is not very large, that is not a big deal.

Answer (score 0):

Try it at the end

```
UPDATE Account Ex
    Set [1f9ae786-9aae-4478-8254-3b683804ccfa] = 'New'
WHERE 
    [1f9ae786-9aae-4478-8254-3b683804ccfa] = 'NEW'
    OR [1f9ae786-9aae-4478-8254-3b683804ccfa] = 'new'
COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS
```

But couldnt you just update to New since you want all variants of new|NEW|NEw|nEw|etc to be New.  Wont hurt to update existing value as it will be set to the same.